# Diff between dataframe values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following dataframes and I want to find out which values are diffrent by `ID`

```
a1 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:4], 1:4), Col1=letters[1:4], Col2=letters[4:7])
a2 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3), Col1=c("a", "c", "b"), Col2=c("f", "e", "d"))


  ID Col1 Col2
1 A1    a    d
2 B2    b    e
3 C3    c    f
4 D4    d    g

> a2
  ID Col1 Col2
1 A1    a    f
2 B2    c    e
3 C3    b    d
```

I would like to have a df like this:

```
  ID    Col1 Col2
1 A1    TRUE  FALSE
2 B2    FALSE TRUE
3 C3    FALSE FALSE
4 D4    FALSE FALSE
```

Edit:
if a dataframe has diffrent columns in addtion, like

```
a2 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3), Col1=c("a", "c", "b"), Col2=c("f", "e", "d"), Col3=c("f", "e", "d"))
```

I would like to have something like:

```
ID    Col1  Col2    Col3
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 A1    TRUE  FALSE FALSE 
2 B2    FALSE TRUE  FALSE 
3 C3    FALSE FALSE FALSE 
4 D4    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: I would suggest to use the wonderful waldo package here. waldo is very user-friendly: `waldo::compare(a1,a2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revised scenario** for unequal dfs

```r
a1 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:4], 1:4), Col1=letters[1:4], Col2=letters[4:7])
a2 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3), Col1=c("a", "c", "b"), Col2=c("f", "e", "d"), Col3=c("f", "e", "d"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

a1 %>% full_join(a2, by = 'ID') %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(!ends_with('.x') & !ends_with('.y'), ~ FALSE),
         across(ends_with('.x'), ~ . == get(gsub('.x', '.y', cur_column())),
                   .names = '{gsub(".x", "", .col)}'),
         .keep = 'none')
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>   ID    Col3  Col1  Col2 
#>   <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 A1    FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 2 B2    FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#> 3 C3    FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 4 D4    FALSE NA    NA
```

---

OR

```r
a1 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:4], 1:4), Col1=letters[1:4], Col2=letters[4:7])
a2 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3), Col1=c("a", "c", "b"), Col2=c("f", "e", "d"), Col3=c("f", "e", "d"))

library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

a1 %>% full_join(a2, by = 'ID') %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(!ends_with('.x') & !ends_with('.y'), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), NA, FALSE)),
         across(ends_with('.x'), ~ . == get(gsub('.x', '.y', cur_column())),
                   .names = '{gsub(".x", "", .col)}'),
         .keep = 'none')
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>   ID    Col3  Col1  Col2 
#>   <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 A1    FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#> 2 B2    FALSE FALSE TRUE 
#> 3 C3    FALSE FALSE FALSE
#> 4 D4    NA    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

As requested in comments, if you want to sort columns as per order in either of df say `a2` here add one line to the end like this

```
a1 %>% full_join(a2, by = 'ID') %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(!ends_with('.x') & !ends_with('.y'), ~ FALSE),
         across(ends_with('.x'), ~ . == get(gsub('.x', '.y', cur_column())),
                .names = '{gsub(".x", "", .col)}'),
         .keep = 'none') %>%
  select(names(a2))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
  ID    Col1  Col2  Col3 
  <chr> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1 A1    TRUE  FALSE FALSE
2 B2    FALSE TRUE  FALSE
3 C3    FALSE FALSE FALSE
4 D4    NA    NA    FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks, is it also possible if  `a2` has also diffrent columns in addition:
`a2 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3), Col1=c("a", "c", "b"), Col2=c("f", "e", "d"), Col3=c("f", "e", "d"))`

Comment: Is it also possible to keep the column order?

Comment: @dev123, column order according to which df?  What if both dfs have uncommon columns?

Comment: @dev123, see if  adding `%>%  select(names(a2))` in the end helps, as suggested in revised answer

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(tidyverse)
a1 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:4], 1:4), Col1=letters[1:4], Col2=letters[4:7])
a2 <- data.frame(ID = paste0(LETTERS[1:3], 1:3), Col1=c("a", "c", "b"), Col2=c("f", "e", "d"))


full_join(a1, a2, by = "ID") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_sep = "\\.", names_to = c("set", ".value")) %>% 
  mutate(res = x == y) %>% 
  pivot_wider(ID, names_from = set, values_from = res)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   ID    Col1  Col2 
#>   <chr> <lgl> <lgl>
#> 1 A1    TRUE  FALSE
#> 2 B2    FALSE TRUE 
#> 3 C3    FALSE FALSE
#> 4 D4    NA    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: can I also use this with the case in my post edit ?

Answer (score 1):

With base functions (without dplyr), you can use a key vector to merge the data frames and compare the columns:

```
key = (1:dim(a2)[1])
names(key)=a2$ID
comparison = data.frame("ID"=a1$ID,
                        "Col1"=a2$Col1[key[a1$ID]]==a1$Col1,
                        "Col2"=a2$Col2[key[a1$ID]]==a1$Col2)
```

The result differs slightly from your expectation, as the `D4` gets missing values instead of `F`. But you can replace the `NA` by any value, if you like:

```
> comparison
  ID  Col1  Col2
1 A1  TRUE FALSE
2 B2 FALSE  TRUE
3 C3 FALSE FALSE
4 D4    NA    NA
```